# How to keep IDE configuration files out of code repository?

Tags: eclipse, svn, ide, netbeans

How can I keep IDE configuration files out of a (svn) repository? The only way I can think of is with very specific "add" and "commit" commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the files to the svn:ignore property.  This has the advantage of being part of the project configuration for everyone that checks it out, not just you.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude (ignore) the `*.suo` and `*.user` files.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with eclipse, I'll speculate that you're perhaps using a plugin.

I use Subversive, and with that, the Windows=>Team=>Preferences=>Ignored Resources tab gives you the ability to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check them in (`svn add`) in the first place.